# Upload multiple files through one single browse button through struts

Tags: java, forms, struts, jsp-tags, struts-html

I have a requirement, wherein I need to upload multiple photos through one single browse button. I am using form-bean concept for achieving the same. The issue is how do I send multiple photos path from JSP to Action via Form Bean? I.E. how do I get multiple paths of photos in action file? I am using the below code to send single photo path from JSP which I have achieved successfully. Please guide me on how to upload multiple photos.

```
    <html:file property="file" styleId="<%=abc%>"
```

How to upload multiple filer through one single Browse Button through struts?

Comment: The `file` field is only able to handle a single file.  The user might put the multiple files into a Zip archive.

Comment: Hi andrew..thank you for your feedback..But this is not my requirement i need to upload multiple photoes not zip or anyother file.

Comment: I need a flying pony.  Doesn't mean I'm going to get one.  And note it is spelled 'photos' - no 'e'.

Comment: I need to do the same as multiple photos getting uploaded in facebook and attachement for Gmail with just a single cliIck.